# Image not scaling with Graphics.drawImage()

Tags: java, image, swing, graphics

I am creating a 2D platformer game and am trying to scale an image with a custom library I created. The code gives a NullPointerException when invoking `dbi.getGraphics()`.

```
public void scale(int width, int height) {

        JFrame tempFrame = new JFrame();
        tempFrame.setSize(source.getWidth(null), source.getHeight(null));
        Image dbi = tempFrame.createImage(source.getWidth(null), source.getHeight(null));
        Graphics dbg = dbi.getGraphics(); // NullPointerException
        dbg.drawImage(source, 0, 0, width, height, null);
        source = dbi;

        //BufferedImage temp = (BufferedImage) source;
        //temp.getScaledInstance(width, height, Image.SCALE_DEFAULT);
        //source = temp;

}
```

I am using `dbi.drawImage()` to scale the image. I have tried `source.getGraphics().drawImage(source,0,0,width,height,null);`, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Is dbi null, or is the NullPointerException being thrown from within the call to getGraphics()?  Posting a few lines of the stack trace would help here.

Comment: @Galen Nare why not you use the getScaledInstance(width, height, hint) method of class Image for Scaling your images??

Comment: @Muhammad: Some perils are cited [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20892645/230513).

Comment: @trashgod I have voted both of your answers because it worth it :)

Comment: @Muhammad because it causes a ClassCastException because a ToolkitImage is being used somewhere and I don't know where. I never create a ToolkitImage...

Comment: If you're trying to create a platformer, the built-in Java Graphics libraries are a very poor choice. Have a look at libGDX. It comes with all manner of support for physics, lighting, particle effects, animations, and all the rest. Furthermore, you can use openGL to implement custom shader programs and all manner of low level graphics tinkering.

Comment: @ScubaSteve I don't really have a choice now, I've already made a lot of progress with what I have. It's a little too late.

Comment: If it's for any kind of commercial release, I think you're crazy. Just on the record there. But good luck :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer to my own question that works.

```
int imageWidth  = source.getWidth();
        int imageHeight = source.getHeight();

        double scaleX = (double)width/imageWidth;
        double scaleY = (double)height/imageHeight;
        AffineTransform scaleTransform = AffineTransform.getScaleInstance(scaleX, scaleY);
        AffineTransformOp bilinearScaleOp = new AffineTransformOp(scaleTransform, AffineTransformOp.TYPE_BILINEAR);

        source = bilinearScaleOp.filter(
            source,
            new BufferedImage(width, height, source.getType()));
```

I found it on another question from a few years ago.

[How to improve the performance of g.drawImage() method for resizing images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3967731/java-scale-image-best-practice)

Answer (score 3):

The frame has not been made visible at this point in your program; `getGraphics()` is invalid. Instead use [`BufferedImage#createGraphics()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#createGraphics--), as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21238669/230513). Also consider `AffineTransformOp`, seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4216635/230513).